# Twitter API for Non-public/organic/promoted metrics in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter API in Google Script to get the non-public metrics of my posts.
I believe have done all of the authentication properly since I am able to get the information when using Postman. I have generate a *consumer_key*, a *consumer_secret*, an *access_token*, and a *token_secret*.
According to the twitter documentation , I MUST use Oauth1.0 (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics).

In order use the Oauth1, I used Google's own script for Twitter Oauth1 (https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/examples/twitter-oauth10).

I was able to take that code (along with the library it required) and successfully retrieve the tweets for my username.

My attempt to get the non_public metric was replacing the "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json" with the GET request I had from POSTMAN but it returned a "401 error".

I have a hunch that I can't just replace that url with my own but I am unsure how to approach it.

In summary:

1. Tokens/Twitter Authorization/GET request are written properly since they work in Postman
2. Google Script is writing properly since the default URL works
3. Unsure how to replace the default url to accomplish different tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up figuring it it out!

I was not supposed to pass the entire url as a replacement for "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json".
It is supposed to be replaced by the "base" url. In my case this was "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets".
I then had to change the variable "params" that feed into it.
*note that the params is from the code provided by Google in my original post*

They have to be in the following format (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/twitter-api-google-sheets):
params = {
"tweet.fields": "author_id,created_at,lang",
"ids": "21,1293593516040269825,1334542969530183683",
}

I was able to add my own fields such as "non_public_metrics,organic_metrics" to get:

params = {
"tweet.fields": "author_id,created_at,lang,non_public_metrics,organic_metrics",
"ids": "21,1293593516040269825,1334542969530183683",
}

I hope this helps someone someday :)

Comment: when you ran the google script, were you logged into the twiiter account you want the metrics for? I'm trying to fetch the data from my company's twitter account but I'm getting `{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}` . I'm using the consumer and access tokens from the company twitter account

Comment: You shouldn't need to be logged in to the Twitter account - I was not logged in earlier and it still worked. I would suggest making sure that all four of your keys are correct (CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET) using Postman. If you get the the same error over there it may be because they keys you are using are not the correct ones.